# Free C++ UI Framework for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, gui, visual-studio

I am new to C++ and i want to add a GUI to my existing project but i don't know which one i should use, i have looked at Qt but i don´t know if there exists something better than this.

- It should be compatible with Visual Studio 2017 to fit for me.
- The framework also should include a designer so it should not be
  coded only but if it is way better i can ignore the fact. But a good
  compatibility with Visual Studio 2017 must exist.
- Cross platform availability of the framework is also really
  important for me.
- I want to draw a simple GUI with sliders, buttons, etc.
- I want to include a small window in my application where a can place
  and move objects in and I want to measure their position.
- It should be free and stable.

Comment: I don't know about how well this (or Qt) integrates with VS, but http://nanapro.org/en-us/ is something to check out. I only saw it yesterday so I can't really say anything good or bad about its quality, but it looks like it may be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using JUCE, it is very simple and also stable! Great Library.